# Convert C# byte array to numpy array in Python .Net

Tags: python, .net, arrays, numpy, python.net

I try to use a .NET Assembly in a python application using Python.NET. The C# code captures an image, that i want to use with python. Let's say I have the following C# method:

```
public static byte[] Return_Image_As_Byte_Array()
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile("C:\path\to\an\image");
        ImageConverter imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] ByteArray = (byte[])imageConverter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
        return ByteArray;
    }
```

When I use Python.Net in python i do the following:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('MyAssembly')
from MyAssembly import MyClass
print(MyClass.Return_Image_As_Byte())
```

This gives me the output:

```
<System.Byte[] at 0xb7ba20c080>
```

Is there a way to turn this image from C# into a native python type like numpy array?

Comment: this looks like resolved here: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/174

Comment: you can just wrap with `list(System.Byte[])`

Comment: @denfromufa this would have a very bad performance

Comment: @dlammy if you need performance, take a look here: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/514

Comment: @denfromufa Yes in fact I've used robbmcleod solution and it's very fast. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to convert C# `Byte[]` to Python bytes first and from that to `numpy` (Python 3.8):

```py
from System import Byte, Array
import numpy as np

c_sharp_bytes = Array[Byte](b'Some bytes')  # <System.Byte[] object at 0x000001A33CC2A3D0>
python_bytes = bytes(c_sharp_bytes)
numpy_bytes = np.frombuffer(python_bytes, 'u1')  # b'Some bytes'
# numpy_bytes is now array([ 83, 111, 109, 101,  32,  98, 121, 116, 101, 115], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking for Performance:**
I found that `np.fromiter()` (numpy) was 6 times faster than the provided answer in @dlammy url link above as response to the question. The used function was `asNumpyArray()`
url: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/514

Since there was such a distinction in times I thought only one timed run would suffice, instead of averaging the results.
My Result:
`np.fromiter()` : 67.914736s
`asNumpyArray()`: 334.5198s

Solution Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61077271/4084346